# Ruby on Rails create a dynamic asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm making a small gem to help me out with further development which creates a small javascript function based on some database resutls. That piece of javascript must be added to the page somehow but I'm not sure of the best way of doing it.

Do the assets pipeline have some magic code that I can add javascript/css code to it somehow? I checked the docs but found nada yet.

Comment: If you include your JS/CSS in your gem's vendor/assets/javascript and vendor/assets/images, they'll be available for inclusion. Then your users will add the code necessary to their HTML page (or require in their application.js). Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. The js file is created with that request. It doesn't exist as a static file.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile:
place your js file in `vendor/assets/javascripts`
In application
add to file app/assets/javascripts/application.js lines:

```
#= require your_js_file_name
```

if you have dynamic pieses of code add extension .erb to your js file
for example: your_js_file_name.js.erb